# script not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="notePad" ng-controller="notePadCtrl">

<textarea ng-model="message"></textarea>
<button ng-click="save()">save</button>
<button ng-click="clear()">clear</button>

<script src="notePad.js"></script>
<script src="notePadCtrl.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
var app = angular.module("notePad", [] );

app.controller("notePadCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.message="";
    $scope.left=function(){
        return 100 - $scope.message.lenght;
    };
    $scope.clear=function(){
        $scope.message="";
    };
    $scope.save=function(){
        alert("file got saved");
    };
)};
```

Comment: What functionality is not working?

Comment: I don't think you can have `ng-app` and `ng-controller` on the same element.

Comment: i referred notepad app file from tutorialspoint.They have done the same.My save and clear buttons are not working

Comment: thanks @user5622133 :)

Comment: @user5622133, Really !! you know the new answer is nothing more than my point , right ? good job !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

there are several issues in this code. first the closing of the controller brackets should be changed

```
app.controller("notePadCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.message="";
    $scope.left=function(){
        return 100 - $scope.message.lenght;
    };
    $scope.clear=function(){
        $scope.message="";
    };
    $scope.save=function(){
        alert("file got saved");
    };
});
```

then add the angular script tag inside the body or head tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="notePad" ng-controller="notePadCtrl">
    <textarea ng-model="message"></textarea>
    <button ng-click="save()">save</button>
    <button ng-click="clear()">clear</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

check out the [pluker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LUggNucc7aPawaPSh1P5?p=preview)

Comment: basically you just change the last line !

Comment: yep and also changed the script tag

Comment: but that does not matter !!, your answer is exactly like me , I don't know why this guy !!!

Comment: I think, the both users are same?? You answering with the fake account? if yes then please go to merge it :(

Comment: this is not a fake

Answer (score 2):

Here is an error! replace the last line.

Replace the `)};` with `});`